# How to implement search like Eclipse "Open Resource" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, regex, eclipse, search

In *Eclipse* we can search files using `*`. Find below image showing _Eclipse search functionality. I want to implement same search in JavaScript. I tried some `Regex` but didn't work perfectly like *Eclipse*.

Is there any `Regex` or algorithm for this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe `.*?Ta.*?py.*?34`

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "Hi this is a test string";

var search = "*st";

search = search.replace(/"\*"/,".");

var matchedResults = string.match(new RegExp(search),"g")
```

matchedResults will contain all the results

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but could you tell me what is x and "g" in (new RegExp(x),"g")

Comment: Sorry, it should be search. I was trying it in console so forgot to change the variable

Comment: g is for checking globally in the string.